# Android SDK: Is Drawable's picture contained in memory?

Tags: android, memory-management, sdk, drawable

If I keep some Drawable in my app, will the picture (which it points to) fully kept in memory? Or is Drawable just a pointer to a file on the drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drawable folder it self not kept as it! However, Your **.apk** is just stored on the device as-is, either on internal storage or external storage as appropriate. Pictures on Drawable will increase the size of the .apk. It will not increase the RAM footprint of the app at runtime. When an app is installed it is kept as its original .apk, so the storage space needed will be basically the size of your .apk

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `apk` is just like installer as you saw in windows. extracting the apk the system stored its relevant conf files to run the application in the device(something like in `/data/data/your_package/...`) paths. All the resources are also located in the `Internal` or `External` SD card location preferred by system or application itself. So don't think about the `RAM` space until the app runs.

[Read a Brief here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package)